# Excel VBA Sum Function

Tags: excel, sum, excel-formula, vba

I got a problem with sum of rows formula in  vba.
I am using the below code. When I check the value in `Range("H3").Formula` its giving me the correct value `=SUM(C5:G5)`

But the problem is its not reflecting in the excel cell.

```
Range("H3").Formula = "=SUM(" & Range(Cells(5, 3), Cells(5, 7)).Address(False, False) & ")"
```

Comment: use `.value` instead of `.formula`

Answer (score 1):

You need to fully qualify the cells (notice the dots). Try this

```
'~~> Replace this with the relevant sheet
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("H3").Formula = "=SUM(" & _
                          .Range(.Cells(5, 3), .Cells(5, 7)).Address(False, False) & _
                          ")"
End With
```